# How can I stream data from a Google PubSub topic into PySpark (on Google Cloud)

Tags: python, pyspark, streaming, google-cloud-pubsub

I have data streaming into a topic in Google PubSub.  I can see that data using simple Python code:

```
...
def callback(message):
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") + ": message = '" + message.data + "'")
    message.ack()

future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback)
future.result()
```

The above python code receives data from the Google PubSub topic (with subscriber *subscriber_name*) and writes it to the terminal, as expected.  I would like to stream the same data from the topic into PySpark (RDD or dataframe), so I can do other streaming transformation such as windowing and aggregations in PySpark, as described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html.

That link has documentation for reading other streaming sources, (e.g. Kafka), but not Google PubSub.  Is there a way to stream from Google PubSub into PySpark?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Apache Bahir](http://bahir.apache.org/)**, which provides extensions for Apache Spark, including a connector for Google Cloud Pub/Sub.

You can find [an example from Google Cloud Platform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-gcp-examples/tree/master/pubsub-streaming) that using Spark on Kubernetes computes word counts from data stream received from a Google Cloud PubSub topic and writes the result to a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket.

There's [another example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-pubsub-spark-streaming) that uses **DStream** to deploy an Apache Spark streaming application on Cloud Dataproc and process messages from Cloud Pub/Sub.

Comment: Those examples are all in scala, whereas I am trying to accomplish this task using python (pyspark), as I will be calling a number of functions that are already written in python.

Comment: You could use a language binding then, or you can use an existing one. For example, check the [python binding of this GitHub project](https://github.com/SignifAi/Spark-PubSub) that enables Apache Spark streaming applications to consume messages from Google Pubsub from Java and Python.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but was getting some cryptic error messages.  After poking around a bit, I saw that Kafka provides a better solution to what we're trying to do, so decided to take that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Beam: https://beam.apache.org/

Apache Beam has Pyhton support for Cloud Pub/Sub: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/

There is a Python SDK: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python/

And support for Spark: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use this: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/samples/pubsublite-spark-streaming-from-pubsublite

You create a subscription and put into option in spark stream.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("read-app").master("yarn").getOrCreate()

sdf = (
    spark.readStream.format("pubsublite")
    .option(
        "pubsublite.subscription",
        f"projects/{project_number}/locations/{location}/subscriptions/{subscription_id}",
    )
    .load()
)
```

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.

Comment: I added some code like you said @AzharKhan. Thanks